# how to make guzzle to send parameter without its name?

Tags: php, json, rest, guzzle

I have such operation description:

```
    "AddContact": {
        "httpMethod": "POST",
        "uri": "icp/a/{account_id}/c/{folder_id}/contacts",
        "summary": "Adds a contact.",
        "responseClass": "IM\\MailingList\\IContact\\Response\\Contact",
        "parameters": {
            "account_id": {
                "location": "uri",
                "required": true
            },
            "folder_id": {
                "location": "uri",
                "required": true
            },
            "contacts": {
                "location": "json",
                "required": true
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is what guzzle sends:

```
{"contacts":[{"email":"email@test.tld","firstName":"firstName","lastName":"lastName"}]}
```

What I actually need:

```
[{"email":"email@test.tld","firstName":"firstName","lastName":"lastName"}]
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only thing I need to do is change `location` of parameter to `body`.